# F#: How can I wrap a non-async value in Async<'T>?

Tags: asynchronous, .net-core, f#, wrapper

In F#, I'm implementing an interface that returns Async<'T>, but my implementation does not require any async method calls. Here's an example of my current implementation:

```
type CrappyIdGeneratorImpl() =
    interface IdGenerator with
        member this.Generate(): Async<Id> = async {
            return System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        }
```

Is this the "best" way to wrap a non-Async<> value in Async<>, or is there a better way?

Put another way, I'm looking for the `Async` equivalent of `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult()`.

Comment: This is totally idiomatic and I believe should be the preferred way. But since `async` itself is an object which defines CE methods you can also use `async.Return value` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the best way.

Note that, as stated in the comment, another way would be to do `async.Return` but it's not exactly the same thing, and in your use case it won't work, due to eager evaluation of the argument.

In your case you're interested in calling the `.NewGuid()` method each time the async is run, but if you use `async.Return` alone it will be evaluated once and the async computation will be created with that result as a fixed value.

In fact the equivalent of the CE is `async.Delay (fun () -> async.Return (.. your expression ..))`

**UPDATE**

As Tarmil noted, this can be interpreted as intended, given that the code resides in a method.

It might be the case that you created a method because that's the way you do with tasks, but Asyncs can be created and called independently (hot vs cold async models).

The question of whether the intention is delaying the async or creating an async at each method call is not entirely clear to me, but whichever is the case, the explanation above about each approach is still valid.

Comment: "in your use case it won't work, due to eager evaluation of the argument." On the contrary, it would be a closer equivalent of `Task.FromResult`, which is also eager.

Comment: I didn't say that, please read again. His use case is not `Task.FromResult`, look at the code fragment. However it's true that at the end of the question he says "put it in another way ..." and ask about `Task.FromResult`, well in that case it worth clarifying: that's not "another way", that's rather a different way if we consider eager evaluation.

Comment: Well, the use case is returning it from a method, and to me it seems intended to be awaited immediately by the caller. In which case the eagerness doesn't matter all that much, you'll get a different `Async` value each time you call the method anyway.

Comment: That's true, from the viewpoint of calling the method and it's worth noting it. But still not a faithful translation strictly speaking.

Comment: Added a note about this,